# How can I shutdown a Windows machine remotely from OS X?

Tags: windows, mac, terminal, shutdown

I'm trying to shutdown a Windows machine remotely from within OS X.

I've seen this a lot on Linux sites but it doesn't transfer over:

```
net rpc shutdown -I xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -U username%password
```

I'm trying to get this command to work from OS X:

```
shutdown /s /f /m \IP_GOES_HERE
```

I have Wine, but I heard it may not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux `net` command is part of the Samba suite, which used to be bundled with Mac OS X too but has been removed from Mac OS X 10.7 due to licensing issues. It still can be manually [compiled](http://samba.org/).

Wine does *not* yet support most of the Windows networking APIs, so `shutdown.exe` is not likely to work.

Comment: And is there an easy way to install that? It seemed pretty crazy to me with the public key and all... How do they not have a binary for mac??

Comment: "The public key" is for verifying that you have the original Samba source code (because server compromises do happen). Verifying it is entirely *optional*. Samba probably does not publish a binary because Apple used to bundle it with OS X up to 10.6 so nobody *needed* to download binaries until recently, and also because Samba consists of *several* command-line binaries and a dozen shared libraries (I think the OS X term is "dylib") that must be put into the right place; it is *not* just something you download and click.

Comment: Okay, then how do I compile the code?